# What program can I use to add album art to music?

Tags: windows-7, itunes, mp3, music, album-art

I have a lot of mp3 files which I get from Game/Anime OSTs, ED/OP Singles and the Collector's Soundtracks that come with Premium or Limited Edition Games. A lot of the time these aren't tagged with their album name, track name and artist (with the exception of some like Disgaea 4, Puela Magi Madoka Magika).

Now I sync all these files to my old iPhone 4 which I now use as my music player (because I have an iPhone 5 and my iPod Touch only has 8GB compared to my iPhone 4 which has 32GB). My computer on which I store all my music, work and games does not connect to the internet, so it's kind of a pain to download .txt files with track information and use Windows to change it manually.

I figure the quickest way to do it is to add album art to all the files and have them grouped correctly in iTunes. While I can do the grouping just fine, I can't add the album art.

I am wondering what program can I use to add album art to mp3 files which would make them still work in iTunes (because if it works in iTunes, it will work for any Apple product I sync it to).

Comment: Well Album Art is just a .jpeg or another picture file, that **isn't** linked in any way to the .mp3.
Look it up on iTunes documentation. Probably you need to make this by hand.

Comment: @Doktoro, Apple devices actually use ID3 metadata for artwork, which is embedded in the .mp3 or AAC music file.

Comment: @DourHighArch You are right indeed but I would like to point two things. First comes [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ID3#ID3v2) link from Wikipedia stating that ID3 isn't supported by Windows or Windows Media Player (although this being a post about iTunes, it only serves to show not everything supports it). Second comes some experience I had with iTunes, that if I recall made it really hard to alter album art.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question leaves a lot unexplained, such as what OS your computer is using and why you don't connect it to the internet. If you connect to the internet you can import artwork using File > Library > Get Album Artwork.

If you refuse to connect to the internet, or want to use your own custom artwork, iTunes itself allows you to add artwork to songs; select the song in iTunes, choose File > Get Info > Artwork, and paste any image file in the dialog. This won't work if the .mp3 file is locked or encrypted.

If you refuse to use iTunes and are using Windows, there are [ID3 editors](http://lifehacker.com/5266613/six-best-mp3-tagging-tools) that allow you to edit ID3 metadata even on encrypted files.

If none of these answers work for you, will will have to provide additional information.

Comment: you can blame jonsca for removing the windows-7 tag i had in there, i'll add it back in in a moment, as for why i don't connect to the internet, security purposes, you can't hack into a computer which isn't connected to any network and viruses and maleware can't get onto it if the files are downloaded onto another computer and scanned with an up to date virus scanner before being transferred, ultimate security

Comment: @Memor-X, I changed my link to a page of Windows ID3 editors. As for disconnecting from the Internet for security... I bet the Iranians thought that too.

Comment: Kim Jong would be proud.

Comment: if you have data you want to protect (in my case, years of work, music, images) then why the hell would you put it on a medium that anyone can gain access to, after all, anything connected the internet can be hacked, would you put your most treasured item on a table in the street in a busy crowed, sure, you can hire the military to guard it but they can still be killed and your item stolen, same thing

Answer (score 1):

iTunes will allow you to add album art stored locally. In my opinion it is a clunky and slow method.

I currently use MusicBee and have used MediaMonkey; both are pretty good.